# Are there historical examples of civilization reaction to learning about impending doom?

Tags: social-history

By impending doom, I mean *events that are deadly, imminent, inexorable and unfightable* (i.e. a volcano eruption, a deadly disease, an environmental/astronomical disaster...). They should leave humans with no choice but to flee or be smart about it. They could happen on a small or big scale, it matters not. What I am after is the reaction of civilization to the news. Did the people come together to surpass this ordeal? Or would they rather be individualistic about it, and save their own hide?

There are two criteria to this question: the "impending doom" event **must have happened** (without necessarily making a great number of victims), and the people **must have known about it** in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about events that potentially could end a civilization? Or just have a large impact on a portion of the civilization?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  How will you choose an [Authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401)?  Please revise to fit within our scope

Comment: @MCW any answer that fits the description may be chosen, I'm not sure if that's within the rules

Comment: Strongly recommend you read the resources I linked, and [good question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote/3885#3885)  THe question you've asked fits a pattern that tends towards rapid closure on our site.  There are plenty of sites for discussion.  H:SE is for authoritative answers based on historical sources and methods.  Alternatively, you could start with [Hebrew prophets](https://rowman.com/ISBN/9780765799982/Messengers-of-God-A-Jewish-Prophets-Whos-Who) and move on to prophets of other cultures.

Comment: @SteveBird perhaps the "deadly" part needs to be defined too. By it, I meant that you could not just ignore the event. Which means the impact on a civilization needs not be civilization-ending. The answer I seek only needs to fit the "deadly, imminent, inexorable and unfightable". Because the impact on civilization is subjective and relative to the people leaving during this time, I can't really give a proper definition for this. Anything from impacting a small village to a whole country is correct.

Comment: @MCW, if I understand correctly you want me to add the research I did that failed and led me to ask this question, right? I did not do that because it would be citing a bunch of events that did not fit the "people knew about it" like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_Pont-Saint-Esprit_mass_poisoning

Comment: I'm trying to say that almost every question that asks for "examples" gets closed as not suitable for this site.

Comment: I believe [this movie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downfall_(2004_film)) deals with one such event.

Comment: @MCW I see, but that's a shame. Part of history is about not repeating the mistakes of the past. To make it a rule to avoid asking about whether a certain situation happened before is missing a big point. If you were to do research and could not find such a piece of information, where should you turn to? An exchange website about history is an obvious answer. Since exchanging information is in the name of this website, it should be expected to ask for others' knowledge on a broader topic that one's knows nothing about. If this question does not belong here, it doesn't belong anywhere else.

Comment: @Jan I had not thought about it from this angle, that's interesting and does fit the description. That is one good example I can dig into.

Comment: Does death of [Pliny The Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliny_the_Elder#Death) count? '*Pliny, ..., was stationed with the fleet at Misenum at the time of the eruption of Mount Vesuvius. He organized and led a rescue mission upon receiving a message from his friend Rectina, .... Pliny boarded one of several galleys that he dispatched across the Gulf of Naples to Stabiae. ... As Pliny's vessel approached the shore ..., cinders and pumice began to fall on it. The helmsman advised turning back, to which Pliny replied, "Fortune favours the bold; steer to where Pomponianus is."*'

Comment: If you're interested in fictional examples, a film depicting World War 3 might work. Here's an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Beach_(2000_film). *The film received mixed reviews because with its three-hour account of impending doom, reviewers considered it "slow going"* (it actually uses the same phrase "impending doom"!)

Comment: Not arguing the points you're making, but the question is not well suited for our site.  I'm summarizing years of discussion on history.meta about what we do well, and what we don't - what generates *answers* and what generates *discussion*.  The question you've asked is likely to generate discussion and is better suited to a discussion oriented site.

Comment: If you want fictional examples, asking on Literature SE or Science Fiction and Fantasy SE would be reasonable.

Comment: @StuartF No, I wanted real examples. I wouldn't be on "history" otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do these events fit your criteria?

- When an invading army breaches the defenses, and everyone in the city know they are likely to die horribly.

[Nanjing Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanjing_Massacre)

> With the relocation of the capital of China and the reports of Japanese brutality, most of the civilian population fled Nanjing out of fear. Wealthy families were the first to flee, leaving Nanjing in automobiles, followed by the evacuation of the middle class and then the poor, while only the destitute lowest class such as the ethnic Tanka boat people remained behind. Three quarters of the population had fled Nanjing before the Japanese arrived.

[Fall of Constantinople (1453)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople)

> When Turkish flags were seen flying above the Kerkoporta, a small postern gate that was left open, panic ensued and the defence collapsed. Janissaries, led by Ulubatlı Hasan, pressed forward. Many Greek soldiers ran back home to protect their families, the Venetians retreated to their ships and a few of the Genoese escaped to Galata. The rest surrendered or committed suicide by jumping off the city walls.
> ...
> A few lucky civilians managed to escape. When the Venetians retreated over to their ships, the Ottomans had already taken the walls of the Golden Horn. Luckily for the occupants of the city, the Ottomans were not interested in killing potentially valuable slaves but rather in the loot they could get from raiding the city's houses, so they decided to attack the city instead. The Venetian captain ordered his men to break open the gate of the Golden Horn. Having done so, the Venetians left in ships filled with soldiers and refugees. Shortly after the Venetians left, a few Genoese ships and even the Emperor's ships followed them out of the Golden Horn. This fleet narrowly escaped prior to the Ottoman navy assuming control over the Golden Horn, which was accomplished by midday.
>
> ... The army converged upon the Augusteum, the vast square that fronted the great church of Hagia Sophia whose bronze gates were barred by a huge throng of civilians inside the building, hoping for divine protection. After the doors were breached, the troops separated the congregation according to what price they might bring in the slave markets. ... The Venetian Barbaro observed that blood flowed in the city "like rainwater in the gutters after a sudden storm" and that bodies of Turks and Christians floated in the sea "like melons along a canal".

- For another example due to a natural disaster:

[Sinking of the Titanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinking_of_the_Titanic)

Many people tried to save themselves, while others largely accepted their fate.

> Some, perhaps overwhelmed by it all, made no attempt to escape and stayed in their cabins or congregated in prayer in the third-class dining room. Leading Fireman Charles Hendrickson saw crowds of third-class passengers below decks with their trunks and possessions, as if waiting for someone to direct them. Psychologist Wynn Craig Wade attributes this to "stoic passivity" produced by generations of being told what to do by social superiors. August Wennerström, one of the male steerage passengers to survive, commented later that many of his companions had made no effort to save themselves. He wrote: Hundreds were in a circle [in the third-class dining saloon] with a preacher in the middle, praying, crying, asking God and Mary to help them. They lay there and yelled, never lifting a hand to help themselves. They had lost their own will power and expected God to do all the work for them.

**In brief**: for most people, if they can run, they run. If they can't run, they pray to God.

Comment: It is definitely helpful and does fit my criteria. Thanks!